# Check for visual presence of character on page?

Tags: html, unicode, character, symbols

I'm in an odd situation where I need to check, via a test, that a currency symbol is being properly displayed on our web page.

We've been running into issues where sometimes the unicode alphanumeric value is showing up on the page instead of the actual currency symbol itself.

Is there a way to check for something like this? Like with some type of visual checking library, or through javascript?

Comment: Did you check why even this issue occur? on any specific browser or anything else? And if you found out how to find this then how will you going to solve it?

Comment: @rohit The issue was with our services team. There was a bug with the values being returned from out API. However, I've been tasked to write a test that catches this type of failure in the future if it ever happens again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue was to specifically copy and paste the unicode character I was looking to test against into my text editor.

So using the Protractor framework, I would find my css element, and if I have a known price of 17.99 that should be returning, my test function would return:

```
return expect(myPriceElement.getText()).to.eventually.equal(£17.99);
```

If on my webpage, £17.99 shows up, then my test will pass